# how to prepare mobile version of dynamic PHP-MySQL desktop website

Tags: css, mobile

I have PHP-MySQL dynamic corporate website. All text and image based content is managed from admin panel. Desktop version website is displaying very fine in mobile phones too. Layout is also fine and structured.

Now I want to create mobile version of this website but I am novice in this field. I have read few topics on this website about mobile version of website but I have found no answers I am looking for. I have also read about responsive website solution.

Please guide me with some helpful info so I can go in right way.

Q 1. If I use responsive website technique, then same website and it's layout will be used for desktop as well as different screen resolution mobile phones? Please reply.

If an answer of above question is 'YES' then please reply for below.

Q 2: Will I need to redesign my existing desktop version website using responsive webdesign technique so it can work in all screen resolutions devices? Please reply.

If an answer of above question is 'NO' then please reply for below.

Q 3. My current desktop website content is managed from admin panel. So if I host mobile version website on sub domain (like m.sitename.com) then will I able to use same content for both main domain as well as sub domain where mobile version website is hosted? Please reply.

Q 4: Is it compulsory to use any tool like http://www.mobify.com/ to design mobile version website? or can I design it in same way as I am doing for my desktop version website? Please reply.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? You can use media queries in CSS to make your website responsive.

Comment: If you've responsive design then you'll need to add only: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`. Also no need to use any third party software or tool. IMHO this question will have several opinion based answers.

Comment: I have no responsive design but I am asking that if I use responsive design then single website will work for both desktop and mobile versions? please clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to answer your questions:

Q1: Yes, if you're using responsive web design you can use the same layout for all kinds of devices.

Q2: Depends on your project, but you'll probably need to rewrite some parts of your layout to make it more responsive.

Q3: Yes, if your code base is somewhat reusable this should be very easy.

Q4: Nope, you don't need any extra tools. You could write everything yourself.

Depending on how complex your front-end stuff is, I'd recommend to use a fronend framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or INSERT_ANOTHER_MOBILE_FRIENDLY_FRONTEND_FRAMEWORK_HERE. These frameworks make it very easy to write responsive websites.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful reply. And same time sorry if my question is too basic for you. But I am unclear about 4th answer. Currently I am designing website in Dreamweaver. So still do I need Bootstrap or Foundation or some other similar front-end framework? 
Or 
Do I need to prepare design first in Bootstrap and then do PHP programming in Dreamweaver like I am doing right now for my websites?